Isomorphism Exterior Power via Basis
The problem is the following:

For a n-dimensional Vector Space V (basis $v_1,..,v_n$) and its dual $V^*$, find a vector space isomorphism from $\bigwedge\nolimits^kV$   to $\bigwedge\nolimits^{n-k} V^*$  ?

My tutor adviced to find a Basis for $\bigwedge\nolimits^kV$ which is given by ${ v_{i_1}, ..., v_{i_k} : i_1<i_2...<i_n } $. A basis $\bigwedge\nolimits^{n-k} V^*$ is defined similarly ${ v^*_{i_1}, ..., v^*_{i_{n-k}} : i_1<i_2...<i_{n-k} } $. How would one define a isomorpism between this ?

Set $N=\{1,\dots,n\}$. If $I\subseteq N$ has $k$ elements, write $I=\{i_1,\dots,i_k\}$ with $i_1<\cdots<i_k$ and denote
$$
v_I=v_{i_1}\wedge \cdots \wedge v_{i_k}.
$$
Note that with this notation, a basis of $\bigwedge^k V$ is given by
$$
\{v_I \; | \; I\subseteq N \text{ and } |I|=k\}.
$$
Consider the unique linear map defined on this basis by
$$
v_I\mapsto v_{N\setminus I}^*.
$$
You can verify that this map sends a basis of $\bigwedge^k V$ to a basis of $\bigwedge^{n-k} V^*$, and consequently is a vector space isomorphism.
